# Is there any upside in taking resveratrol supplements in addition to pterostilbene supplements?

Tags: anti-aging

Is there any upside in taking resveratrol supplements in addition to pterostilbene supplements?

---

Some sources I have read so far pterostilbene seems to be a superior replacement of resveratrol. E.g.:

1. https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/beyond-resveratrol-the-anti-aging-nad-fad/:

> Why pterostilbene instead of resveratrol?

> While resveratrol has hogged the anti-aging spotlight over the past decade, unsung researchers in places like Oxford, Miss., have quietly shown that pterostilbene is a kind of extra-potent version of resveratrol. **The pterostilbene molecule is nearly identical to resveratrol's except for a couple of differences that make it more "bioavailable"** (animal studies indicate that about four times as much ingested pterostilbene gets into the bloodstream as resveratrol). **Test-tube and rodent studies also suggest that pterostilbene is more potent than resveratrol** when it comes to improving brain function, warding off various kinds of cancer and preventing heart disease.

2. http://www.pterostilbene.com/pterostilbene-vs-resveratrol/:

> Benefits of resveratrol are well-documented because there has been so much money and lab time devoted to studying it in the last decade, both in animals and in humans. Pterostilbene is a similar compound, rarer and more bioavailable.

While some of the sources seem to claim resveratrol complements pterostilbene:

http://www.lifeextension.com/magazine/2009/ss/The-Other-Resveratrol/Page-01:

> How Pterostilbene and Resveratrol Work Together?

> Pterostilbene and Gene Expression: The Key to Longer Life
> Scientists have found that resveratrol activates genes near the beginning of the molecular cascade precipitated by caloric restriction. These in turn activate a broad array of disease-preventing genes. In essence, resveratrol’s beneficial genetic action takes place “upstream.”

> Pterostilbene directly activates genes “downstream” from the sites of resveratrol’s action. This complements resveratrol’s ability to help prevent cancer and diabetes, and support healthy blood lipids. **Acting together, resveratrol and pterostilbene produce potent longevity-promoting effects** across the cycle of gene expression through complementary mechanisms.

---

I am looking for scientific evidence.

Comment: I have read, but have not researched, that that pterostilbene increases low-density lipoprotein (LDL) bad cholesterol. So you may want to look into that. I think pterostilbene has some benefit for certain conditions,  but I would not use it long term unless it was supervised by a doctor.

Comment: Pterostilbene on Metabolic Parameters: A Randomized, Double-Blind, and Placebo-Controlled Trial https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4099343/